# Second CollectionView in row doesn't display in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a problem. I created a pair CollectionView in one flex layout, bot the second CollectionView does not display at all.

Here is my xaml code:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="BooksListView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding BooksList}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <FlexLayout x:Name="BookCard" Direction="Column" x:DataType="model:Book">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                           LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                           Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle }"
                           FontSize="20" />

                    <CollectionView x:Name="genresList" ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" >
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Genre">
                                <FlexLayout Padding="10" Direction="Column">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </FlexLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <CollectionView x:Name="AuthorsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Author">
                                <FlexLayout Padding="10" Direction="Row">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </FlexLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </FlexLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

This is what it looks like:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UBDC.png)

Comment: CollectionView with HorizontalList probably takes the entire row, so there is room in case you add more items. On each CollectionView, set WidthRequest. OR consider putting them in cells of a grid, rather than FlexLayout.

Comment: nesting CollectionViews or ListViews is generally not a good idea

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you I've changed layout to GridLayout and everything works fine